# gRPC Channel throws null reference exception in Blazor client

Tags: c#, grpc, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I've a `gRPC` service written in `.NET 6` that is running fine on localhost. I'm trying to consume it in a `Blazor` client for .NET 6. but, I'm getting `System.NullReferenceException` when creating that channel for my `gRPC` service.

**SERVICE HELPER**

```
public class ServiceHelper : IServiceHelper
{
    public Server.ServerClient? ServerClient { get; set; }
    public ServiceHelper()
    {
        try
        {
            GrpcChannel channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:7027");
            ServerClient = new Server.ServerClient(channel);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs for Client**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddAntDesign();

//var serviceAddress = builder.Configuration["ServiceAddress"];

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IServiceHelper, ServiceHelper>();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

**Using the gRPC Client**

```
@inject IServiceHelper _serviceHelper

<div class="page elementFillSpaceY">
  
</div>

@code
{
    public ServerStatus? ServerStatus { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await SetUpData();
    }

    private async Task SetUpData()
    {
        var client = _serviceHelper.ServerClient;

        if (client != null)
        {
            var result = await client.GetServerStatusAsync(new Empty());
            ServerStatus = result;
            Debug.WriteLine(ServerStatus.Status);
        }
    }

}
```

**Program.cs for gRPC Service**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
const string corsPolicy = "_corsPolicy";
/*builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: corsPolicy,
        policy =>
        {
            /*policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7075",
                    "http://localhost:5025")
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .WithExposedHeaders("grpc-status", "grpc-message")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});*/

var app = builder.Build();
//app.UseCors(corsPolicy);
//app.UseRouting();
//app.UseGrpcWeb();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
app.MapGrpcService<ServerService>();
app.MapGet("/",
    () =>
        "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client.");


app.Run();
```

I've tried different ways of consuming `gRPC` service in client e.g. Dependency Injection for Channel and on `gRPC` side look at the commented code that i have tried but still getting same error. It just throws the null reference exception without any other detail.

[image: Exception Image]

**Stack trace of exception**

> 'at
> Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.BalancerHttpHandler..ctor(HttpMessageHandler
> innerHandler, HttpHandlerType httpHandlerType, ConnectionManager
> manager)\n   at
> Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel.CreateInternalHttpInvoker(HttpMessageHandler
> handler)\n   at Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel..ctor(Uri address,
> GrpcChannelOptions channelOptions)\n   at
> Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel.ForAddress(Uri address, GrpcChannelOptions
> channelOptions)\n   at Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel.ForAddress(String
> address, GrpcChannelOptions channelOptions)\n   at
> Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel.ForAddress(String address)\n   at
> BusinessBlazor.Helpers.ServiceHelper..ctor() in ....'

Comment: What reference leads to a null? Is this a GrpcChannel equals null or something inside the ForAddress method is null?

Comment: @GoodboY i did not create `ForAddress` method it is provided by the `gRPC`.

Comment: What is in the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @GoodboY I've added stack trace. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure why the exception is thrown. But, with a pretty high probability, it may be thrown because the `GrpcChannel.ForAddress` can not construct a valid HttpClient for the communication. Possible steps to debug and fix this issue

1. Ensure that your server is actually up and accessible via the URL `https://localhost:7027`
2. Try to construct and pass the `HttpClient` explicitly. See example [here](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/03/15/How-to-use-gRPC-Web-with-Blazor-WebAssembly-on-App-Service.html). Also, note that in the client service you registered the `HttpClient` as `Scoped`, so you won't be able to fetch it from DI container in the `Singleton` service.
3. Try to add the gRPC client via `builder.Services.AddGrpcClient` and get it from the DI. Example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/clientfactory?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

I really hope that it will help to solve your problem. Good luck!